# What is the purpose of under score in when declaring a IBAction func?

Tags: swift, function, ibaction

Beginner question, I realise that when the Xcode declares a function for @IBAction, it declares it as below:

`@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton)`,
which I read is,

> Create a function called hardness selected which accepts a parameter
> called sender which accepts the type UI button.

From my understanding so far _ is used when you want to declare a variable that you are not going to mutate e.g. in a for loop to tell swift the value of this variable doesn't matter to optimize performance.

However, in the above case there is a name for the variable "sender" as well as _ which I don't understand why.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: underscore allows you to omit the parameter name when calling the method `hardnessSelected(aButton)`instead of `hardnessSelected(sender: aButton)`

Comment: Please see “omitting argument labels” on https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This place is declared for the label which means that once you call the function it won't appear to you for example:

```
   func sum (_ number1: Int, _ number2: Int) {
    print(number1 + number2)
}
```

once you call the function you won't need to mention number1 or number2 but you will only write the number directly :

```
sum(1, 2)
```

To be clear it's the same as using the function below:

```
func summation(myFirstNumber number1: Int, mySecondNumber number2: Int) {
    print (number1 + number2)
}
```

but here instead of using _ I've used a label so when I called the function, I will use these labels :

```
summation(myFirstNumber: 1, mySecondNumber: 2)
```

So it's clear now that _ is instead of writing a label.

For more information check:  Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names from [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Swift allows having an `argumentLabel` different than actual `argument` itself for better readability.

---

In case your function signature is like this -

```
func value(for key: String)
```

In this case, these values are `argumentLabel == for` & `argument == key`. At the call site, you have to mention the `argumentLabel` like following.

```
value(for: "myCustomKey")
```

---

In case your function signature is like this -

```
func valueForKey(_ key: String)
```

In this case you are explicitly asking compiler to allow you to omit `argumentLabel` while calling this function. Please note that `argument == key` will not be visible at call site for this like following.

```
valueForKey("myCustomKey")
```

---